# Django - put value from one view to another

Tags: django

This is a part of my template file:

```
{% for tag, value in tags.items %}
    <a style="color: {{value.1}}; font-size: {{value.2}}px " href="{% url 'tags' tag|slugify  %}">{{ tag }}</a> ({{value.0}}),
{% endfor %}
```

Url looks like: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag/my-simple-url/

I need to get "my-simple-url" as my "simple url" in my next view. Now it looks like:

```
def tags(request, slug):
    context = {}
    tags = Tags().tag_filer_sites(slug.replace('-', ' '))
    context['slug'] = slug
    context['tags'] = tags['sites']
    return render(request, 'mainapp/all_tags.html', context)
```

but I have to use full name instead of slug. How can I achieve that? I need to find a way to put tag into url or get it in different way but I don't know how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
def tags(request, slug):
    context = {}
    tags = Tags().tag_filer_sites(slug.replace('-', ' '))

    context['slug'] = slug
    context['full_name'] = Tag.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    context['tags'] = tags['sites']

    return render(request, 'mainapp/all_tags.html', context)
```

Comment: I don't have a Tag model. I have to get something like Site.objects.filter(keywords__contains=slug) but instead of slug I need a full keyword( slug is my-simple-word, I need my simple word).